# Extracting Multiple Numerical Values from String in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset where I would like to extract only the numerical values from the following string:

```
{  "What are the last three digits of your zip code?": "043",  "What are the last three digits of your phone number?": "681"}
```

Specifically, I would like to extract this as two separate columns (043 and 681). Is there a way to do this with these symbols in the string?

Comment: Is this JSON content, and, if so, why do you have such key names?

Comment: I don't think so and the format is from Microsoft Bookings - You can ask "customers" extra questions on there and, for whatever reason, it doesn't create separate columns for these extra questions... just lumps it all into one cell with this odd formating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `str_extract_all`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(str1, "\\d+")[[1]]
#[1] "043" "681"
```

If there are more than one element, we can do

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
tibble(col1 = str2) %>%
    mutate(col1 = str_extract_all(str2, "\\d+")) %>%
    unnest_wider(c(col1)) %>%
    set_names(str_c('col', seq_along(.)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  col1  col2 
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 043   681  
#2 313   681
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "{ \"What are the last three digits of your zip code?\": \"043\", \"What are the last three digits of your phone number?\": \"681\"}"

str2 <- c('{  "What are the last three digits of your zip code?": "043",  "What are the last three digits of your phone number?": "681"}', '{  "What are the last three digits of your zip code?": "313",  "What are the last three digits of your phone number?": "681"}')
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I think this is a good start as it extracts the numbers into characters and I can just convert it into a data frame, however, it doesn't seem to work if I have multiple rows like below

`{  "What are the last three digits of your zip code?": "043",  "What are the last three digits of your phone number?": "681"}
{  "What are the last three digits of your zip code?": "313",  "What are the last three digits of your phone number?": "681"}`

It only extracts the first one. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: That makes a 2 obs 4 variables like the following:
043 | 681 | 313 | 681
043 | 681 | 313 | 681 
@akrun

Comment: @ChrisWiese Can you show the dput of the string.  I assume these are of length 2 and not of 1

Comment: @ChrisWiese Please check the updated exxample in my data and the output I am getting

Comment: The output? [Here](https://imgur.com/HrGnn15) is a screenshot

Comment: @ChrisWiese I can't copy from the image.  Please check the data I showed in my post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231041/discussion-between-chris-wiese-and-akrun).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option using `strsplit`

```
> Map(function(x) x[nchar(x) > 0], strsplit(str1, "\\D+"))
[[1]]
[1] "043" "681"


> Map(function(x) x[nchar(x) > 0], strsplit(str2, "\\D+"))
[[1]]
[1] "043" "681"

[[2]]
[1] "313" "681"
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R Solution:

```
# Split numeric values into separate columns: df => data.frame
df <- data.frame(
  do.call(rbind, do.call(c, lapply(list(str1, str2), strsplit, "\\D+")))
)

# Subset data.frame to exclude blanks; correctly name vectors: res => data.frame
res <- setNames(df, paste0("col", seq_along(df)))[, colSums(df == "") < nrow(df)]
```